# Drop down menu hidden behind javascript slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, overlap

Currently my nav menu's drop down portion is being hidden behind the javascript slider I have directly below it. See the problem [here](http://konecny.dyndns.biz). How can I have the drop down menu display over the slider?

Here is some of the CSS for the two divs that contain the respective nav menu and slider.

Nav Menu:

```
#nav {
width:1024px;
height:20px;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Slider:

```
#slider {
width:1024px;
height:300px;
background: #353A33;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "PHP dropdown menu". There's only webpages that PHP happens to have generated, which perchance contain menus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding a `z-index` to your `.dropdown` class:

```
 /* Navigation Style */
.dropdown {
  position:relative;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#ffffff;
  background:#353A33;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use 
position:absolute
with highest z-index on your nav